# Image Categorization Using Gist Descriptors

Tags: graphics, machine-learning, computer-vision, classification, libsvm

I created a multi-class SVM model using libSVM for categorizing images. I optimized for the C and G parameters using grid search and used the RBF kernel.

The classes are 1) animal 2) floral 3) landscape 4) portrait.

My training set is 100 images from each category, and for each image, I extracted a 920-length vector using Lear's Gist Descriptor C code: http://lear.inrialpes.fr/software.

Upon testing my model on 50 images/category, I achieved ~50% accuracy, which is twice as good as random (25% since there are four classes).

I'm relatively new to computer vision, but familiar with machine learning techniques. Any suggestions on how to improve accuracy effectively?

Thanks so much and I look forward to your responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very very very open research challenge. And there isn't necessarily a single answer that is theoretically guaranteed to be better.

Given your categories, it's not a bad start though, but keep in mind that Gist was originally designed as a global descriptor for scene classification (albeit has empirically proven useful for other image categories). On the representation side, I recommend trying color-based features like patch-based histograms as well as popular low-level gradient features like SIFT. If you're just beginning to learn about computer vision, then I would say SVM is plenty for what you're doing depending on the variability in your image set, e.g. illumination, view-angle, focus, etc.

Comment: I included 6 DOF features using Daubechies wavelet transformations and the accuracy jumped to 61%! I'll look into SIFT/SURF and patch-based features. Please let me know if you think of any other features I could use! Thanks :D